# Get the supported Bluetooth Version in Android phones?(5 or 4.x)

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, android-bluetooth, android-ble

Is there a way to know the Android Bluetooth Ver?( 5 or 4.x - 4.1 or 4.2?)
Currently as per

`https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes`

Feature like Advertisement packet length ~ 60 bytes of more than usual (that is 31 bytes) or Support for LE Extended Advertising are features for Bluetooth 5.

Is checking these APIs below  (for True) can guarantee that the Bluetooth 5 is supported?

Also is it possible to know the Bluetooth ( though they come in WiFI Combo) chip version?

```
isLe2MPhySupported()
isLeCodedPhySupported()
isLeExtendedAdvertisingSupported()
isLePeriodicAdvertisingSupported()
getLeMaximumAdvertisingDataLength() > 31 ( for Bluetooth 5)
```

I have read that by getting the Physical MAC of the device we can know to which Brand  the chip-set is as different vendors have purchased these MACs from the Bluetooth Org?

Assist please !

Answer (score 2):

Yes if **any** of the APIs listed above returns true, then your device supports Bluetooth v5. The reason that there isn't a clear cut 'version' API is that Bluetooth is now more about features than it is about hardware version. You can have a device that contains Bluetooth 5 hardware, but will not support any of the Bluetooth 5 features such as 2MPHY, CODED PHY, or LE Advertising Extensions. Therefore it is more useful to have a feature by feature check of your hardware.

You are correct in that different companies have different MAC addresses assigned to them. You can find the full list [here](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/company-identifiers). For example, theoretically speaking, Apple MAC Addresses should start with 00:4C:XX:XX:XX:XX. However, I say theoretically because not everyone abides by this, and as a user you sometimes have the option to change your MAC address, making this information redundant.

I hope this helps.